# Prove the A-G-M Inequality using Lagrange multipliers.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I’m trying to prove the Arithmetic-Geometric-Mean Inequality (A-G-M) using Lagrange multipliers. For positive real numbers $ x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n} $, we want to show that
$$
(x_{1} x_{2} \cdots x_{n})^{1/n} \leq \frac{x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n}}{n}.
$$
Consider the function $ f(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}) = x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{n} $ subject to the constraint
$$
x_{1} x_{2} \cdots x_{n} = c,
$$
where $ c $ is a constant.

So I’m using Lagrange multipliers to solve this. I get $ \dfrac{1}{n} = \dfrac{\lambda c}{x_{i}} $ for all $ 1 \leq i \leq n $. Then $ \dfrac{x_{i}}{n} = \lambda c $. Then the sum of all the $ \dfrac{x_{i}}{n} $-terms yields $ x_{i} = \lambda cn $. I’m not sure where to go from here, or if I’ve made a mistake somewhere. Any tips?

Comment: So that proves the AGM the case of equality, yes? I'm not clear on where the inequality comes from. When xi does not equal xj?

Answer (score 1):

Your result shows that all the $x_i$ are equal
to $n \lambda c$,
so their product is
$(n \lambda c)^n$.

If this equals $c$,
$c = (n \lambda c)^n$
so
$\lambda = c^{-1+1/n}/n$
and the sum of the $x_i$ is
$n^2 \lambda c
=n^2 c (c^{-1+1/n}/n)
=n c^{1/n}
$
and each $x_i$ is 
$c^{1/n}
$.